# How can I rename the element <dc:creator> to <author> in my RSS?

Tags: feed

I need to change the author element of the feed from dc:creator to author. How does this is possible?

Comment: <author> and <dc:creator> are not the same thing - the <author> element should contain the author's email address. See this trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15136

Comment: Ok done it. You should add it as an answer

Comment: Done what? I don't really regard my comment as an answer, it's a warning about the difference between <author> and <dc:creator>

Comment: I have placed the `<author></author>` inside the feed-rs2.php

Comment: ok, but that's not what I've suggested, and that's not a good way of doing it, as when you upgrade WordPress you'll lose your change. Have a look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bearing in mind my comment about, you can use the `rss_item` hook to add a filter that will let you add the `<author>`element to your feed

```
function add_author_to_feed($feed) {
  $feed .= '<author>' . the_author_meta('user_email') . '</author>';
  return $feed
}

add_filter('rss_item', 'add_author_to_feed');
```

(note - this code is not tested)